# Many apps crashing on phone after Google app disabled and re-enabled

Tags: gmail, google, crashes

The Google app was taking up half a gigabyte of storage even though I never use it, so I cleared its data and disabled it. After I did this, Gmail and Outlook crashed, so I re-enabled the main Google app. Gmail and Outlook were still failing, however.

Since the main Google app was now an earlier version, I thought maybe I should update it. Although I can open the main Google app, it crashes as soon as I switch to the "Update" tab, so that's not an option. I also tried clearing my Gmail and Outlook data to see if that would help, as well as disabling and re-enabling Gmail, but neither had any effect.

I've also cleared all data from Google Play Services and restarted my phone to no avail. If I try to visit Google settings from the Settings app, then the Settings app freezes. What can I do to make these apps operable again? Note that not all Google apps are afflicted. For example, I can still use Drive, YouTube, and the Play Store.

For a little more detail, the Gmail is receiving data. I can see new messages for the half-second that the app is open before  it crashes. If I try to send a crash report, the crash-report-sending services crashes too.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge running Android 8.0.0.

EDIT:

Previously I wrote of only a few apps that have crashed. As I have tried to use more, I have found that apps unrelated to Google have crashed -Stack Exchange being one of them, as well as an open source reader app (that wasn't even installed through the Play Store, it was installed through F-Droid), a game, and the built-in Samsung text messenger app.

In recent verbal conversation, someone suggested that I may have unintentionally deleted a security token, and that is causing the widespread malfunctions. However, he does not know how to get a new one if that is the case, and of course neither do I.

EDIT 2:
In the early afternoon today, about 24 hours after the initial problem, the main Google app managed to update itself without any intervention from me and everything came back online. Perhaps there is a 24-hour check for updates that Google performs for built-in apps automatically outside.of the app store. In any case, once this occurred, the other apps which had been compromised began to function as well, so now everything is back to normal.

Comment: You can try to manually download the Google apps from https://opengapps.org and manually install the newest version of those apps you have disabled/reset, especially Google Play Services and Play Store.

Comment: Thank you. Frankly, I don't know how to install those. I've installed from APKs before but not tars. Also, I've updated the post with additional information that may help. Based off the breadth of non-Google apps that are crashing, and the timing of the crashes, it sounds like it's an authentication problem rather than version incompatibility.

Comment: Tar is just an archive format extract it and identify the APK files you need. You don't need all of them just the relevant I mentioned to get Play Store working again so you can update the other apps via Play Store.

Comment: Thank you! In the early afternoon today, the main Google app managed to update itself without any intervention from me and everything came back online. Perhaps there is a 24-hour check for updates that Google performs for built-in apps automatically outside.of the app store.

Comment: Great to hear you are back up and running.  Yes, Google Play will force itself to update, and I am currently unaware of any way to prevent this from happening.  In your case, it wound up being a good thing (until all the Google bloat fills up your device again), although in some cases it is not.

Comment: Yes! I'll just clear caches without disabling the apps next time...

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of a few dozen little apps, each supplying an API or a service, Google changed the scheme (a few years ago) to incorporate all of them in one app.  Most Google apps depend on it, many non-Google apps depend on it.

I'd try uninstalling all the non-system apps that are crashing (you can't uninstall a system app unless the device is rooted), update the Google app (again), update the Google system apps and reinstall all the uninstalled apps.  (If that doesn't work, reflashing the ROM - and losing anything not backed up - may be your only resort.)

Comment: Thank you! As noted above in the second edit and the comments, the problem has been resolved. However, this is good information, so it's worth an upvote. For what it's worth, uninstalling and reinstalling non-system apps unfortunately did not help.